# Unable to install package psych on macOS using Revolution R Open 3.2.2

Tags: r, macos, gfortran, install.packages, microsoft-r

I try to install the psych package on macOS with Revolution R Open 3.2.2. I used `install.packages("psych")` and all the dependencies are going to be downloaded.
The first dependency was successfully unzipped.

The following happens afterwards:

```
gfortran -arch x86_64   -fPIC  -g -O2  -c biv-nt.f -o biv-nt.o

gfortran -arch x86_64   -fPIC  -g -O2  -c sadmvnt.f -o sadmvnt.o

clang -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -L/Users/Shared/Jenkins/workspace/External-R-3.3.2/vendor/build/lib -o mnormt.so biv-nt.o sadmvnt.o -L/usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin8/4.2.3/x86_64 -L/usr/local/lib/x86_64 -L/usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin8/4.2.3 -L/usr/local/lib -lgfortran -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/Shared/Jenkins/workspace/External-R-3.3.2/vendor/build/lib'

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin8/4.2.3/x86_64'

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/lib/x86_64'

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin8/4.2.3'

ld: library not found for -lgfortran

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

make: *** [mnormt.so] Error 1

ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘mnormt’

* removing ‘/Users/sebastian/Library/R/3.3/library/mnormt’

Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘mnormt’ had non-zero exit status

ERROR: dependency ‘mnormt’ is not available for package ‘psych’

* removing ‘/Users/sebastian/Library/R/3.3/library/psych’

Warning in install.packages :

  installation of package ‘psych’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in

  /private/var/folders/8d/tdsm42091lz926w1q2lx77c40000gn/T/RtmpHxWPQe/downloaded_packages
```

My system:

```
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Sierra 10.12.1
```

This also happens for other packages, but not for all. I installed ggplot2, dplyr or tidyr and everything just worked fine.

Comment: key line: `ld: library not found for -lgfortran`; install [`gfortran`](https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/tools/)

Comment: Do not install `gfortran 4.2.3`. Got to the libs directory on [here](http://R.research.att.com/libs/) and look for `gfortran` and read the notes at the end of the file.

Comment: Thanks for the first answers. @Bhas: I tried the following: `curl -O http://r.research.att.com/libs/gmp-4.2.4-darwin8-bin4.tar.gz
sudo tar fvxz gmp-4.2.4-darwin8-bin4.tar.gz -C /` some files are copied in different folder, but when it comes to copying into `usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0/4.8.2/`the error `Cannot extract through symlink usr/local/lib/gcc`occurs

Comment: Sorry for double posting... I installed gfortran as @hrbrmstr suggested and now the psych package and all dependencies are installed properly! I only installed gcc beforehand, which was not enough...

Comment: I have `gfortran` with GCC 5.3.0 installed but still getting this error. Also I have XCode 8.2.1 as well. Anything to do with the version of gfortran? Any other suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue with many other R packages when I switched to `MRO` on `MacOS`. It could be two things:

1. You are missing `gfortran`, like @hrbrmstr mentioned in the comments.
2. Or, you have `gfortran`, but the link library path was not specified by the compiler, as you can see in the error messages before it bummed out at the `gfortran` line.

The solution to 2, which worked for me, is to edit `~/.R/Makevars` to add your `GCC/GFortran` libraries. For `GCC5`:

`LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/lib/gcc/5`

Comment: Thanks for the 2nd tip! As for now, `gfortran` is part of `gcc` package, so just install `gcc` and add the path (`gcc/7` now)

Answer (score 2):

Installing gfortran alone did not help in my case. Make sure that XCode is installed and uptodate. This helped me.